# Integrate Jacobi polynomials $w_{a+\epsilon,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)$ with slightly modified weight

Tags: integration, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

It is well-known that the Jacobi polynomials satisfy the orthogonality relation
$$\int^1_{-1}w_{ab}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx=\frac{2^{a+b+1}\Gamma(k+a+1)\Gamma(k+b+1)}{(2k+a+b+1)\Gamma(k+a+b+1)k!}\delta_{kl}\,,$$
where the weight function is given by $w_{ab}=(1-x)^a(1-x)^b$. I am trying to get evaluate the same integral with slightly modified weight, namely
$$
I_1(\epsilon)=\int^1_{-1}w_{a+\epsilon,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx=\int^1_{-1}(1-x)^\epsilon w_{a,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx\,,\\
I_2(\epsilon)=\int^1_{-1}w_{a,b+\epsilon}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx=\int^1_{-1}(1+x)^\epsilon w_{a,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx\,,
$$
i.e., the weights are just slightly modified. In the end, I would like to take the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon=1$. I can imagine that this calculation gets cumbersome, but I don't even quite know where to start.

Comment: The derivative will be a real pain in the butt, because
$$I_1'(\epsilon)=\int^1_{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}(1-x)^\epsilon w_{a,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx$$
$$=\int^1_{-1}\log(1-x)(1-x)^\epsilon w_{a,b}(x)P^{a,b}_k(x)P^{a,b}_l(x)dx$$
The $\log$ will make things very difficult here.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely aware of this. In fact, the whole setup is in order to compute this integral including the log without actually having the log, but rather first compute $I_j(\epsilon)$ analytically and then taking the derivative. I know from a related calculations that there will be terms of the form $\Gamma(\cdots+\epsilon)/\Gamma(\cdots)$, such that the overall result after the derivative can be written in Digamma functions.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good way forward here. I think maybe your best bet is to use a first order binomial approximation
$$(1-x)^\epsilon\approx 1-\epsilon x$$